# Disabling an ESLint rule for a specific file not working

Tags: javascript, eslint

In the codebase I'm working on the no-magic-numbers rule is set for the whole project. Thing is that I need to disable that rule for a single file that's using a lot of substrings and it doesn't make sense at all to create a variable for each substring index.

In order to ignore the rule for the whole file, I tried using the automatic lint-disable:

```
/* eslint-disable no-magic-numbers */
```

But ESLint is still complaining about the use of magic numbers.

On the other hand, ignoring the rule for the next line does work:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
```

But since there are way too many places where this rule is being broken and that doesn't make sense to create a constant for each, this is cluttering my code a lot.

Why is it not ignoring the rule for the file when using `/* eslint-disable no-magic-numbers */` at the start of the file?

**EDIT 1**

Apparently, using `/* eslint-disable no-magic-numbers */` in the code instead of at the start of the file will work for ignoring the rule in a certain scope. It's better than disabling for each line but still not the desired result.